# what commands are being run by VS to publish .net core serverless applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-toolkit

Im reading this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-build-test-severless-app.html

I created a serverless app using the "Blog API using DynamoDB" template.

When I publish from VS it deploys it to aws as a serverless app, but what commands is it running? How can I publish it from the command line (without VS)?

When I look at the serverless.template file the project comes with I just see parameter and resource definitions for `AWS::Serverless::Function`s and the dynamodb table- where is the pointer/config that register this as a "Application" in the lambda console- and not just a bunch of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using the [Serverless Application Model](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) (or SAM for short). It's an abstraction on top of standard Cloudformation templates - it allows you to declare serverless application resources in a more succinct way. It also comes with a [CLI](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli). My guess would be that's what's running behind the scenes.

You can try it by yourself. After [installing](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) the SAM CLI, run [sam build](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-quick-start.html#gs-ex1-setup-local-app), [sam package and sam deploy](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/docs/deploying_serverless_applications.md). That should get you off the ground.

```sh
sam build --template serverless.template # --use-container if necessary, needs Docker
sam package --output-template-file packaged.yml --s3-bucket ARTIFACTS_BUCKET
sam deploy --template-file packaged.yml --stack-name my-serverless-app --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Comment: the template says its running `dotnet lambda...`. Does that compile and then run `sam build`? Id like to run these steps separately- first compile, run tests, then build, package deploy from command line

Comment: Honestly, I don't use Visual Studio, so I don't know what `dotnet lambda` does, but it's probably something similar. You can use these three commands separately, from the command line, as you wish.